# Replacing characters in list

Tags: python, string, list

i write a little game 
in short, the user see hidden word and need to guess letters that my appear.
i success most of it, but it fails to complete the words when letter appear in the word more than once.

```
def len_of_word(word):
   return word.replace(word,'_'*len(word))

def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
    hidden = len_of_word(secret_word)
    new_string = list(hidden)
    x = 0
    for i in old_letters_guessed:
       if i in secret_word:
          x = secret_word.find(i)
          new_string[x] = new_string[x].replace(new_string[x], i)
    return " ".join(new_string)
print(show_hidden_word("aviva" , ['m', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'v', 'o', 'm']))
```

in that case the print will be

a v i _ _

Comment: `find` only finds the first occurrence in a list. You might want to iterate over your word and check against the `old_letters_guessed`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `secret_word` instead of `old_letters_guessed`. To keep your structure:

```
def len_of_word(word):
   return word.replace(word,'_'*len(word))

def show_hidden_word(secret_word, old_letters_guessed):
    hidden = len_of_word(secret_word)
    new_string = list(hidden)
    x = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(secret_word):
       if l in old_letters_guessed:
          new_string[i] = l
    return " ".join(new_string)
print(show_hidden_word("aviva" , ['m', 'a', 'i', 'r', 'o', 'm']))
```

Output:

```
a _ i _ a
```